# how to show data on the gsp screen from multiple tables that share a common value?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

lets say I have three tables

- Trips
- TripLegs
- TripStates

when the user create a `Trips` record, he is required to create `TripLegs` and `TripStates` as well.

- Trips: id, trip_number, trip_description
- TripLegs: id, trip_id (is every trips record's Id), Load_type, stop_number
- TripStates: id, trip_id (is every trips record's Id), state_name, stop_number

So my question is on edit screen, how can I get the data from `TripLegs` and `TripStates` that when their `trip_id` is equal to id for the `Trips` column.

```
def edit() {
    def TripsInstance = Trips.get(params.id)

     def tripId = new Integer(TripsInstance.id) Storing the TripInstanceID                   
     def tripLegsInstance =       

     TripLegs.findByTripId(tripId?.toString().toInteger(),  
     [sort:'tripNumber']) 




     def tripStatesInstance =  
     TripStates.findByTripId(tripId?.toString().toInteger(),
     [sort:'tripNumber'])
```

okay so my code works fine, I can retrieve data from three tables to the edit screen but I am struggling on the update method, how do I get the new instances stored?

Comment: you write a query that captures and binds the data returns the results as a list to your view - its custom query which requires custom gsp controller service calls not something you generate from CRUD

Comment: exactly, it is something cant be done with CRUD.. 
can you help me with writing the query?

Comment: please post your domain and gsp code.

Comment: at the moment you are triggering 3 separate lookups and in bottom 2 cases really ? `findByTripId`  ?
how about 
 `TripLegs.findByTrip(TripsInstance) ` which  `def TripsInstance =` should really be   `def tripsInstance =`  lowerCase starting point for variables.

Anyhow all that could be simplified in a `hql ` statement you could write it in criteria builder if you wish and to do so you need to provide the relationship of Trips with tripLegs and tripStates does Trips hasMany of those defined /

Answer (score 1):

Please add the domain model and association code for:

- Trips
- TripLegs
- TripStates

based on you code example I can assume both TripLegs and TripStates are belongsTo Trip(s) and the relationship is One-to-many.
if so you can access the TripLegs and TripStates by querying the Trip by Id

```
Trip myTrip = Trip.get(id)
myTrip.legs 
myTrip.states
```

if you add the domain model and association code you can get more specific help

Comment: absolutley, the whole question and even corrected answer below by quinmildev is really an overkill to get something that already has a relationship and just needs this +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the finders for TripLegs and TripStates

```
Trips tripsInstance = Trips.get(params.id)

//This criteria returns a list of tripLegs related with trip
List tripLegs = TripLegs.findAllByTrips(tripsInstance)

//This criteria returns a list of tripStates related with trip
List tripStates = TripStates.findAllByTrips(tripsInstance)
```

Now you have a Trip, and their TripLegs and TripStates in two list.

Return them to the gsp this way in your edit action

```
[trip: tripsInstance, tripLegs: tripLegs, tripStates: tripStates]
```

and you can show the information on your gsp with a `<g:each>` for each list.

```
<g:each in="${tripLegs}" var="tripLeg"/>
```

Note that I assumed that your classes are something like this:

```
TripState{
   Trips trips //it is mapped as trip_id
}
```

Comment: Great! You are welcome. Mark the question as solved if one of the answers helped you, or give you own answer.